# How to convert below code used for the database connection using EF 6 to async task in C#?

Tags: c#, async-await, entity-framework-6

I am trying to create the `async task` for the already existing code in my project for the database connection using EF 6.

I have created async task and it works fine, you can refer `Using Async Task` section for the code. But I want to rewrite `The existing code of the project` section as `async task` to maintain the consistency in the project.

**Using Async Task:** The below code works fine.

```
public static async Task<Student> InsertAsync(Student student)
{
  try
  {
    using(PracticeContext context = new PracticeContext())
    {
      Repository<Student> repository = new Repository<Student>(context);
      return await repository.InsertAsync(student);
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(ex);
    return null;
  }
}
```

**The existing code of the project:**

I want to implement the below code as `async task` for both the `Insert()` and `Execute()` methods. So, that the data will be added to the `database` without holding the UI for the long time and make the project more user friendly.

Please suggest or provide the `async implementation` of the below codes.

```
public static Student Insert(Student student)
{
  try
  {
    return Execute<Student, Student>((repository) => {
      return repository.Insert(student);
    });
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(ex);
    return null;
  }
}

private static TResult Execute<TResult, T>(Func<Repository<T>, TResult> func) where T: class
{
  using(PracticeContext context = new PracticeContext())
  {
    try
    {
      return func(new Repository<T>(context));
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(ex);
      throw new Exception("Error Occured.");
    }
  }
}
```

I would be glad to add more stuffs if required to make the questions more accurate and understandable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you do is change the lowest-level call to use the asynchronous version and use `async` in its enclosing method/lambda. Then let the `async` grow from there. So the first step would be:

```
    return Execute<Student, Student>(async (repository) => {
      return await repository.Insert(student);
    });
```

This code then requires `Execute` to allow [asynchronous delegates](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/02/synchronous-and-asynchronous-delegate.html). At this step, we probably want other code to continue using the synchronous `Execute`, so we can copy/paste it and make the new overload take an asynchronous delegate:

```
private static async Task<TResult> Execute<TResult, T>(Func<Repository<T>, Task<TResult>> func) where T: class
{
  using(PracticeContext context = new PracticeContext())
  {
    try
    {
      return await func(new Repository<T>(context));
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(ex);
      throw new Exception("Error Occured.");
    }
  }
}
```

Now that the asynchronous `Execute` returns a `Task<T>`, we then need to `await` it back in the calling method:

```
    return await Execute<Student, Student>(async (repository) => {
      return await repository.Insert(student);
    });
```

which then makes the calling method asynchronous as well:

```
public static async Task<Student> InsertAsync(Student student)
{
  try
  {
    return await Execute<Student, Student>(async (repository) => {
      return await repository.Insert(student);
    });
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(ex);
    return null;
  }
}
```